# How to know if a register is a "general purpose register"?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I am trying to understand what criteria a register must have to be called a "general purpose register".

I believe a general purpose register is a register that can be used for anything (for calculation, for moving of data to/from it, etc.) and is a register that doesn't have a special purpose.

Now I have read that the `ESP` register is a general purpose register. I guess the `ESP` register can be used for anything, but the `ESP` register also have a special purpose, which is to point to the top of the stack.

So does that mean that `ESP` register is a special purpose register?

Comment: dont get worked up in terminology.  It is not consistent nor does it need to be, the author of the document and perhaps a few other folks get to decide, per document what the terms mean.  It doesnt have to be more accurate than that.

Comment: general purpose in general means you can use it in general for instructions.  x86 the notion of general purpose is a bit odd as the instruction set didnt start that way and was sort of mangled into it later, but if you can encode a register into the various instructions like add, sub, xor, mul, as well as loads and stores and other such things, then it can be used generally across the instruction set.  Likewise if there are instructions without an encoding for a register because a specific register is used, then that is special purpose.  And no reason why a register cant be both.

Comment: If I understand your question `ESP` is nothing but the `SP` (stack pointer) for i386 and later 32-bit register sizes. For an excellent web reference for Assembly see [**The Art of Assembly Language Programming**](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/AoATOC.html). While it is primarily written for 8086, all principles are 100% applicable to current assembly programming. The only differences are register sizes, calling conventions and syscall numbers for x86_64.

Comment: [**A Direct Link to 8086 Registers**](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/HelloWorlda3.html#998367)

Comment: [what is special purpose register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5840055/995714)

Answer (score 16):

The term *General purpose register*(GPR) stands in contrast to *Special purpose Register*. The latter cannot be used in all contexts.

Historically the old 8086 architecture introduced this difference for integer registers present in their names till today:

- AX = ***A**ccumulator register*: accumulates the result(**)
- BX = ***B**ase register*: base offset for certain instruction, e.g. [XLAT](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/XLAT:XLATB.html)
- CX = ***C**ounter register*: counts for loops, e.g. [JCXZ](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html).
- DX = ***D**ata register*: extends the data range, e.g. the result of [MUL](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html) is in DX:AX
- SI = ***S**ource index*: source for string instructions, e.g. [LODSB](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LODS:LODSB:LODSW:LODSD:LODSQ.html)
- DI = ***D**estination index*: destination for string instructions, e.g. [STOSB](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html)
- SP = ***S**tack pointer*: points to the current item of the stack
- BP = ***B**ase pointer*: points to the base of the current subroutine (stack frame)

> (**) AX/AL is some kind of special purpose register, too. Many instructions have special encodings for AX/AL as operands, e.g. loading segment registers with [MOV](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).

Other *Special Purpose Registers* were

- Segment registers (CS,DS,ES,SS)
- Flags register (FLAGS) and
- Instruction Pointer (IP)

Some of these restrictions are used till today in the addressing mode for 16-bit instructions in *real-mode* (See [*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) Volume 2, Section 2.1.5, Table 2-1. "16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte")

---

With the introduction of the 32-bit architecture - IA-32 - the purpose of the integer registers generalized and (nearly) each register can be used for every purpose (hence general purpose). This also reflects in the addressing mode encoding of the instructions, see *Intel Manual Volume 2, Section 2.1.5, Table 2.2*. (Compare Table 2.1 with Table 2.2 to get an idea of the difference)

The names got prefixed with an *E* and an *R* to *EAX* and *RAX*, respectively, and their historic names indicating the usage are now merely conventional.

With many new architectures new special purpose registers were added. A complete overview is given in the *Intel Manual, Volume 1, Section 3.7.2.*:

> - 32-bit general-purpose registers (EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, ESP, or EBP)
> - 16-bit general-purpose registers (AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, SP, or BP)
> - 8-bit general-purpose registers (AH, BH, CH, DH, AL, BL, CL, or DL)
> - segment registers (CS, DS, SS, ES, FS, and GS)
> - EFLAGS register
> - x87 FPU registers (ST0 through ST7, status word, control word, tag word, data operand pointer, and instruction
>     pointer)
> - MMX registers (MM0 through MM7)
> - XMM registers (XMM0 through XMM7) and the MXCSR register
> - control registers (CR0, CR2, CR3, and CR4) and system table pointer registers (GDTR, LDTR, IDTR, and task
>     register)
> - debug registers (DR0, DR1, DR2, DR3, DR6, and DR7)
> - MSR registers

---

A *general purpose register* is one that can be used for more than one purpose. These purposes are

- value
- addressing
- indexing
- (counting)
- (base)

A *segment register*, for example, can only hold a segment value but cannot be used in an addition. And a *FPU register* can only hold a floating points value but cannot be used for addressing.

In IA-32 the *ESP* register is closer to being a *general purpose register* because it can be used for (nearly) all of the above purposes:

- as value: `mov eax, esp`
- in addressing: `mov eax, [esp+4]`, but **not** as (scaled) index like `mov eax, [4+esp*2]`
- as base: `mov eax, [esp + eax]`
- as count: `inc esp` before a jump is valid

The only exception for `ESP` is that the *(scaled) index* addressing cannot be encoded. It can only be used as a *base register* which is exceptionally encoded with a SIB-byte (see Intel Manual, Volume 2, Section 2.1.5, Table 2.3 - see footer).

To illustrate the difference in encoding between *ESP* and the other registers (e.g. *ECX*):

```
8b 01         mov eax, [ecx]   ; MOV + ModRM (normal)
8b 04 24      mov eax, [esp]   ; MOV + ModRM + SIB byte
8b 41 04      mov eax, [ecx+4] ; MOV + ModRM + disp8
8b 44 24 04   mov eax, [esp+4] ; MOV + ModRM + SIB + disp8
```

I guess despite this one exception `ESP` can still count itself a *GPR*.

Comment: `[eax + esp]` is only encodeable as `[esp + eax*1]` (with EAX as the index).  It's not the scaling per-se that's the problem, it's that ESP can't be an index, only a base register.  Most assemblers will take care of this for you, unless you force one or the other to be the index.  [ESP] as base always needing a SIB byte is a bit like [EBP] always needing a disp8/disp32.

Comment: Why do you say "contrary to 8086"?  All the registers were less general-purpose (because of lack of `movzx/movsx`, lack of 2-operand `imul`, etc.), and 16-bit addressing-modes are much more limited.  But you could still use SP as a loop counter with `dec sp / jnz` if you wanted to.  (If you don't need a stack).  Or use it instead of `[si]` to loop through an array with `pop` instead of `lods`, like I did in [32-bit extended-precision Fibonacci code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618/30206)

Comment: Interesting to mention that in IA-32, some registers are still implicitly bound to some instructions

Comment: @PeterCordes: I attempted to improve the answer by using your suggestions. However, I did no major restructuring.

Answer (score 2):

*Every* general-purpose register in x86 is also used implicitly by certain instructions, and is therefore *also* a special purpose register. Here's just one example for each register, but there are many more examples.
eax: mul
ebx: xlat
ecx: shl
edx: div
edi: stos
esi: lods
ebp: leave
esp: ret

Comment: there are also r8-r15 which I believe are not used implicitly by any instructions

Comment: A still-relevant use for `ebx`: [`cmpxchg8b`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG8B:CMPXCHG16B.html).  Then your examples are all instructions that modern compilers still actually use.  Well actually, they don't use `lods`, but they do use `movs`.   Anyway, that's not relevant your point, but it's interesting that all of the low 8 registers are special for something even in modern compiled code.