# Copy current value of instruction pointer into another register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Why is it possible to do something like:

```
mov %rbx, %rcx
```

But not to do:

```
mov %rip, %rax
# lea (%rip), %rax
```

Why is this the case, and how does `call` go about calculating the return address?

Comment: Because the `rip` is not a general purpose register and has no encoding. The `lea` is legal and works, however. `call` basically uses `rip` as the return address as that already points past the current instruction in the x86 architecture.

Comment: @Jester ok, so then `call func` basically does: `sub $8, %rsp`; `lea %rip, %rax`; `mov %rax, (%rsp)`; `jmp func` (ignoring that the instructions themselves will alter the return address) ?

Comment: How instructions work "internally" is not limited to the operations which the ISA makes available to machine code

Comment: @harold thanks, could you please explain that a bit? I'm very new to assembly.

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it works. You also need to ignore `rax` and flags being overwritten.

Comment: Look in the x86 documentation to see what each instruction does and what the possible operands are.

Comment: My answer on [Why can't you set the instruction pointer directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150027) has some conceptual discussion about general-purpose registers vs. special registers that need special instructions or addressing modes to access them.  Also [How to know if a register is a "general purpose register"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45538667) has more about that concept.  Are those answers what you were looking for with your question about how call can work?  IDK why you have a commented-out RIP-relative LEA; that solves everything in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 The CPU vendor can do whatever he wants to implement an instruction.  He does not need to implement more complex instructions exactly in terms of simpler instructions.